# Multi array_merge

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I'm having a bit of difficulty merging a multi-dimensional array based on 1 index.  I don't know if I've just been racking my brain too long and have messed myself up or what, but I can't get this.

An example of 2 indices from 2 arrays is as such:

```
// Array1:
[0] => Array
    (
        [appID] => 58510
        [name] => SomeRandomApp
        [users] => Array
            (
                [0] => randomUser
            )

    )

// Array2:
[0] => Array
    (
        [appID] => 58510
        [name] => SomeRandomApp
        [users] => Array
            (
                [0] => anotherUser
            )

    )

// Desired Result:
[0] => Array
    (
        [appID] => 58510
        [name] => SomeRandomApp
        [users] => Array
            (
                [0] => randomUser
                [1] => anotherUser
            )

    )
```

I'd like to merge based on "appID" and nothing else.  And then do another merge on users so that if another index has different users, they all just merge.

Comment: Whats the question/problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Merging arrays where the 'users' index can have different data, and merging that as well into the same index.  I'll edit the question and elaborate a bit more.  I've tried array_merge and array_merge_recursive.  I've also tried writing a few functions that would go loop through the two arrays comparing them index by index and merging the ones that had appIDs that matched up.  It wasn't very good though, and took a bit longer to process than I'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it all worked out.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($data as $item)
{
   $appID = $item['appID'];
   $users = $item['users'];

   unset($item['users']);
   unset($item['hoursOnRecord']);

   if(!isset($newArray[$appID]))
   {
      $newArray[$appID] = $item;
      foreach($users as $user)
         $newArray[$appID]['users'][] = $user;                  
   }
   else
   {
      $users2 = $newArray[$appID]['users'];
      $newArray[$appID] = $item;

      foreach($users as $user)
         $newArray[$appID]['users'][] = $user;
      foreach($users2 as $user)
         $newArray[$appID]['users'][] = $user;
   }
}
```

It's pretty sloppy, but it works, and it works pretty damn well if I do say so myself.  Haven't benchmarked it yet but I did test it against a pretty heavy array with no real noticeable delay.  There's a LOT more data in each index than what I'm showing.  All in all, I'm content.

I hope this'll help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get a list of users for each app.  I think you will have to loop through them.  You could created a result array indexed by the appID like this (not tested):

```
function app_users($array1, $array2) {
  $combined = array ();
  foreach (array($array1, $array2) as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $values) {
      if (!isset($combined[$values['appId']])) {
        $combined[$values['appID']] = $values;
      }
      else {
        $combined[$values['appID']]['users'][] = $values['users'][0];
      }
    }
  }      
}

$result = app_users($array1, $array2);
```

This assumes the same user won't be listed twice.  You can modify the function to handle duplicates if necessary.

As a side note, array_merge will overwrite values in the first array with the second in the case of duplicate keys, which I don't believe is the behaviour you want here.

Comment: I tried it just to see what output I'd get, and it returns a blank array.  (I didn't simply copy+paste)  Also, I don't want it to overwrite, I want to combine the sub-array users.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew, have you try to use `array_merge_recursive()` instead?

Comment: I have, posted that in a comment on the original post.  I get the exact same output.  I'm working on writing a function to handle it right now.  It's working well so far, but I'm getting some duplication issues.  Think I might have to throw in some array_unique calls to stop them.  :(